# how to indicate citations from the same, long document at different pages

Tags: publications, writing, citations

I am proofreading a grant from another researcher. This is going to be submitted to the NIH which follows AMA guidelines. A particular, long report is providing her several of the researcher's citations. I asked for page references to some of her stats since I couldn't read the whole thing, and I needed to verify her correctness in interpreting them. This document is hundreds of pages long and she cites 3 different sections in the article.

1) Is it necessary for her to indicate the actual pages in the citations

if so,

2) How to cite the same document at several locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AMA citation guide does not accept *ibid*, *op cit*, or *loc cit* references. Their protocol is listed here:

http://jeffline.jefferson.edu/Ask/Help/Handouts/Citation_AMA_style.pdf

and the basic recommendation is that endnote references should include page numbers when necessary e.g.

> In his early work, Smith found a significant difference between smokers and non-smokers<sup>8(p.23)</sup> Age was also a factor. <sup>8(p.64,66)</sup>

Answer (score 8):

When citing a specific page or pages of a longer document (not generally necessary for published journal articles although that may also be mandatory in some fields) one adds the page number to the reference. In the Harvard system one would write "Smith (1969, p. 24)" or "(Smith, 1969, p. 25)". There are as far as I know no hard rules when such references should be made but an author should consider the readers of the work they produce and facilitate finding the information cited as well as possible. In a short article of 10-15 pages this would not be difficult but in longer works one should consider providing pages. The point of references is after all to provide sources for information used in the article and one should not have to read an entire book to find it.

If I understand the second question correctly, citing different pages in a specific document is done as above and the reference in the reference list will be just the document itself; no need to refer to page numbers there. The reference list provides the litterature to find and the in-text referenes will provide information on where in the literature you need to look.

Comment: (+1) but I can't accept it as an answer since I needed to apply some edits to my question and the citation mechanism you're using is not an accepted method. Basically, we are using AMA guidelines where you don't supply author/year but instead give a reference by number to the bibliography.